# Spring Security - How to get authenticated object in non-secure and secure pages?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, thymeleaf

I have a Spring-boot/Thymeleaf application with two ends point:

1: /int/*: requires sso/authorization;
2. /ext/*: public pages, everyone can access;

Using a PreAuthenticationFilter, I was able to secure /int/* pages. When an user tries to access the /ext/* pages, I'd like to be able to tell in the controller if the user has previously been authenticated (by accessing a secured page).  Currently I save the authenticated Principal object in the HTTP session in UserDetailsService's loadUserDetails().  Just curious if this is the right way (or a better way) to do it.

Comment: Show your Spring Security configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You can get your authenticated object via @AuthenticationPrincipal annotation instead of getting the object from httpsession and casting it back to your object for every controller method.

Let me give you an example, given login page is a public page and User object as below:

**User Class:**

```
public class User implement UserDetails {
    String contact;
    Integer age;
}
```

**Controller:**

```
@GetMapping(value = "/login")
ModelAndView login(@AuthenticationPrincipal User user) {
    if (user == null) {
        return new ModelAndView("/login");
    } else {
        return new ModelAndView(new RedirectView("/home"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Chris - Thanks for taking the time to respond. Maybe my question isn't clear. I'm not asking how to get the AuthenticationPrincipal when a page goes through the authentication process (implemented the way you suggested), but currently when an user access /ext/* page after /int/* page, the AuthenticationPrincipal is null.

I thought the Authentication object should be stored in the session and that I should be able to retrieve it even when the user navigates to a non-secure page later on?